# PHP function can return different & multi-values at first sight, but it can not

Tags: php

```
<?php

function some_func(){

 return 'some_str_type' && 'another_str_type';
}

function another_func(){

 return '123' || '456';
}


print some_func(); //1 - the same as true

print another_func(); //again prints 1, as true
```

The clean style of coding of any language dictates, to drop non-small function into small ones - because one function SHOULD return single value.

**BUT**, i saw this approach in source of some popular php-template langs (smarty, dwoo).
So what is that? When to code this way? (mean any real-world situation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP will return 1 value. What you are doing above is you type an expression, that is evaluated, and the resulting boolean is returned.

```
return 'some_str_type' && 'another_str_type';
```

becomes

```
return true && true;
```

becomes

```
return true;
```

When to use in real life:

```
function some_func(){
   $success1 = doStuff1();
   $success2 = dostuff2();
   return $success1 && $success2;
}
```

it will return true if both called functions return true.

Comment: And last example with or would return true if at least one is true.

Comment: The expression is indeed parsed as you would expect from a logical expression :)